# If value range then... Or if value range between then... Etc

Tags: php, calculator

I'm currently busy developing a PHP price calculator for window decorations, but I'm up against a little challenge (at least for me it is).

Some curtains have a height of 140cm, so if a customer has a window of 200cm high, he will need two pieces of 140cm below each other.

For the calculator i would like to specify the following ranges (height):

---

**1 piece of fabric:**   1cm until and including 140 cm

**2 pieces of fabric:**  141cm until and including 280cm

**3 pieces of fabric:**  281cm until and including 420

---

So when the customer enters a height of 200cm, the calculator knows that he will need 2 pieces of fabric (and that the width of the windows needs to be multiplied by 2).

```
    $aantalbanen = ($_POST["hoogte"]);

switch ($aantalbanen){

    case ($aantalbanen>= 100 && $aantalbanen<= 140): 
        echo "within range 1";
    break;

    case ($aantalbanen>= 141 && $aantalbanen<= 280): 
        echo "within range 2";
    break;

    case ($aantalbanen>= 281 && $num<= 420): 
        echo "within range 3";
    break;

    default: //default
        echo "within no range";
    break;
 }
```

Currently working with the CASE function, but that is getting a bit messy if I need to copy the calculation every time I add a range.

I hope things are clear (since English is not my first language :p) and someone can help me get started!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please show what you tried already. Usually SO is not a good place to get you started, but get you free, when you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done this for you (Including form). I'm using HTML5's input type `number` so only a number can go in and it also has a `minimum` and `maximum` number.

```
<form method="post" action=""> <!-- goes to same page -->
    <input type="number" min="1" max="420" name="height" placeholder="Height">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['height'])){ //doesn't error on page if not set

    $height = $_POST['height']; //create a variable


    if ($height >= 1 && $height <= 140){ //if 1 to 140
        $pieces = 1; //variable for pieces
    }elseif($height>=141 && $height<=280){ 
        $pieces = 2;
    }elseif($height>=281 && $height<=420){
        $pieces = 3;
    }
    else
    {
        $pieces = 0; //You won't need anything, it's not within the limits.
    }

    printf("You will need %d pieces!", $pieces);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Haven't had any HTML5 experience, so my current HTML form is normal HTML... Have had difficulties making the input numerical only, but this is a perfect and simple solution!

Comment: Use `type='number` :) Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You need a form tag like this to enter the user data

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
    <input type="text" name="height">
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

You also need a php page (which can be the same page as above or a different page 'submit.php'

```
<?php

if ($_POST['height'] > 1 && $_POST['height'] <= 140) {
    $pieces = 1;
} else if ($_POST['height'] > 140 && $_POST['height'] <= 280) {
    $pieces = 1;
} else if ($_POST['height'] > 281 && $_POST['height'] <= 420) {
    $pieces = 1;
}

echo "you need $pieces pieces";
?>
```

Comment: I'm now working with CASE, but it's getting a bit messy. I think this way is much more efficient to work with!

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
if($height>1 && $height<=140) {
    $pieces = 1;
} else if ($height>141 && $height<=280){
    $pieces = 2;
} else if ($height>281 && $height<=420){
    $pieces = 3;
}
```